# Where is the RemovePreviousVersions property in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Can someone tell me *exactly* where the RemovePreviousVersions property is in a Setup Project in Visual Studio 2008? I feel like I'm in the Twilight Zone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the SetupProject in the Solution Explorer(View -> Solution Explorer)  and open the Properties Window (View -> Properties Window)
And there is it. :)